# Unable to compare byte slices

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to write a unit test case, where I'm using `reflect.DeepEqual` to `compare` computed and expected results. One of the entries in the struct is a byte slice and DeepEqual keeps on failing it.

Sample Code https://goplay.space/#OcAPkK-EqDX

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var a = []byte("qwedsa")
    var b [6]byte
    copy(b[:], a)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a, b), len(a), len(b), cap(a), cap(b))
}
```

Comment: `reflect.DeepEqual` returns `false` here  because  `a` and `b` have different types (`a` has type `[]byte`, whereas `b` has type `[6]byte`) and [_values of distinct types are never deeply equal_](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual). Try `b := make([]byte, len(a))` instead.

Comment: `DeepEqual` is also unnecessarily heavy for comparing bytes as it's reflection-based. Just use [bytes.Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal), that's what it's there for.

Comment: @Adrian Good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reflect.DeepEqual(a, b)` returns false because you are comparing two types.

`var a = []byte("qwedsa") //here a is a slice with length 6`

`var b [6]byte //here b is a array with length 6`

You can use different options to Do this as mentioned in below.

1. `reflect.DeepEqual(a, b[:]) //by getting a slice from b array`
2. use this instead of reflect package because reflect is not good for performance as [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) mentioned in his comment

`bytes.Equal(a, b[:])`

3. create `b` directly as a slice with length of `a` if there is no need to use it as an array.

```
var b = make([]byte, len(a))
bytes.Equal(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
package main
import "bytes"

func main() {
   var (
      a = []byte("qwedsa")
      b [6]byte
   )
   copy(b[:], a)
   println(bytes.Equal(a, b[:]))
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes#Equal

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions you have to convert your `byte array` to `byte slice` and use `bytes.Equal` .Here is the implementation of the same:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a = []byte("qwedsa")
    var b [6]byte

    sliceb := b[:]
    copy(sliceb, a)
    fmt.Println(bytes.Equal(a, sliceb))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```